# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unrecognized Chrome version: HeadlessChrome RobotFramework

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to use google-chrome headless feature in my ubuntu machine to run selenium scripts headless .Following is the script that I am running

## headless.robot

```
  *** Settings ***
    Documentation     This example demonstrates how to use current library
    Library      Selenium2Library

    *** Test cases ***
   Open Browser with Chrome options in headless mode
        ${options}  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
        Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --start-maximized
        Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --headless
        Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --disable-gpu
        #Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --remote-debugging-port=${9222}
        Create WebDriver  Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
        Go To    https://www.google.com    
        ${title}=    Get Title    
        Log to console    ${title}
```

## pybot headless.robot

```
==============================================================================
Headless :: This example demonstrates how to use current library              
==============================================================================
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
Open Browser with Chrome options for configuring data source          | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unrecognized Chrome version: HeadlessChrome/59.0.3071.86
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 3.13.0-119-generic x86_64)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Headless :: This example demonstrates how to use current library      | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /var/robot-tests/output.xml
Log:     /var/robot-tests/log.html
Report:  /var/robot-tests/report.html
```

## chromedriver --version

ChromeDriver 2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac)

## google-chrome --version

Google Chrome 59.0.3071.86

## Dependency modules installed

```
apt-get install -y xvfb fluxbox x11vnc dbus libasound2 libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libxss1 libpython2.7 libqt4-xml libaudio2 fontconfig liblcms1 lib32stdc++6 libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 nano
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade the [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) to the latest - currently v2.30; this issue should be fixed in v2.29 (and yours is older).
Also, [according to the doc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/headless/README.md) you need to uncomment the `remote_debugging_port` argument.

Btw, unrelated, the variable is called `${options}`, but you are passing in desired_capabilities `${preferences}` - a copy and paste error?

Comment: Thanks for answer @Todor , i will try to update my chromedriver version and update the answer. preferences part is copy-paste mistake by me while posting question.

Comment: This issue is solved after upgrading to latest chromedriver version 2.30.. Thank you @Todor